# ClassCastException trying to import SSL cert in IBM WebSphere

Tags: ssl, websphere, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to import a SSL certificate in a WAS production enviroment as mentioned in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21592616 but, in before the last step (Click OK to add the new certificate to the list), I'm getting the next error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.websphere.models.config.security.impl.SecurityImpl incompatible with javax.management.AttributeList
>     at com.ibm.ws.console.security.SignerCerts.SignerCertsController.setupCollectionForm(SignerCertsController.java:156)
>     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.action.BaseController.perform(BaseController.java:401)
>     at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processTilesDefinition(TilesRequestProcessor.java:242)
>     at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:308)
>     at com.ibm.isclite.container.controller.InformationController.processForwardConfig(InformationController.java:207)
>     at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:279)
>     at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1486)
>     at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:528)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1384)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:104)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:852)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:785)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:325)
>     at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1070)
>     at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:273)
>     at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:455)
>     at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:319)
>     at com.ibm.isclite.container.controller.InformationController.processForwardConfig(InformationController.java:207)
>     at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:279)
>     at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1486)
>     at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:528)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1384)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
>     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistence(WSCUrlFilter.java:927)
>     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:494)
>     at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:315)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:852)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:785)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3610)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:274)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:926)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
>     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
>     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
>     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
>     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:272)
>     at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1016)
>     at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:639)
>     at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1772)
>     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
>     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)

The WAS version is 7.0.0.0. The SSL cert is from https://web.sedeb2b.com/EdiwinWSPre/services/WSEmisionSoap

¿Is there an alternative way to import SSL cert in WAS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to consider installing the latest fix pack.
Version 7.0 has been released over four years ago and tons of bugs has been fixed since that time: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27014463